# How to get the original referrer url on success page?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, php-5.3, magento-1.8

I have a code that its executed only on the head tag of the success page. This code is to track if the buyer is coming from Comission Junction.

I need to set a variable to true if the original referrer comes from commission junction affiliate links which looks like this:

http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-1245-2342423?SID=TrackingTest

is there an easy way to do this?

I was thinking about referral url but I guess that variable changes each time you go from page to page: add to cart -> billing address -> shipping address -> payment -> overview -> success

My code is

```
    public function getCommissionJunctionUdo($orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $udo = array();
            $udo['CID'] = 'XXXX';
            $udo['TYPE'] = 'XXXX';
            $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
            $udo['OID'] = $orderId;
            $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

            $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
            if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code)) {
                $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
            }

            $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);       

            if(referral url come from CJ) 
{
                $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
            }
            else {
                $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
            }

            $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
            $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

            return $json_masterTmsUdo;

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe the event `controller_action_predispatch`.
it is dispatched for every page in magento.
Then you can check if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (or `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER')` if you want to be "politically correct") matches your needs.
If so, then set a value to the session.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setComissionJunctionReferer(true);
```

Then, in your checkout page you can just check if the value is set.

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getComissionJunctionReferer()) {
    //your magic here
}
```

Comment: why not the controller_front_init_before, I found also this link which seems very helpful, you agree with that approach? I just have to change my login in the captureReferral method with your code. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/06/creating-an-affiliate-tracking-module-in-magento/

Comment: I wouldn't use `controller_front_init_before` because when this event is dispatched magento does not know yet if it's on the frontend or backend area. It will work with that event also, but your code will run for the admin part also. And I don't think you need that. If you use `controller_action_predispatch` you can declare your observer to be used only for the frontend area.

Comment: The example looks ok. it might be exactly what you need. Try it, but change the event if you don't want to add an unneeded small overhead on the backend.

Comment: how can I declare the observer to run only for the frontend part?

Comment: @L.V.. Put the `<events>` tag in `config.xml` under the `<frontend>` tag instead of `<global>`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the referrer page's URL if there exists any. try it

Comment: but if I move from page to page then in a new page inside my site it will have the previous one and not the original referrer?

Comment: thats right, so try to store it into a session variable, e.g. $_SESSION['my_referer'] at the 1st call of your page, u know its form the affiliate link

Answer (score 0):

L.V try below

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```

Comment: isnt it the referrer of the current page only? or the entire session?

Comment: then its not what I need, I need the current afiliate url that the user linked in the external site.